# how can 2 function share common variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, function

```
    var ques=["Qno 1", "Qno 2","Qno 3","Qno 4","Qno 5","Qno 6","Qno 7","Qno 8","Qno 9","Qno 10"];
var ans  =[1,2,3,4,5,6, 7,8,9,10];
function random()
{
  var qno=Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) );
  return qno;
}

function validate()//here need help
{
  var Rans=document.getElementById("numb").value;
  if (Rans == ans[qno])
     alert("validated!!!");
  else 
     alert("Not a valid entry.. declined!!!");
}
function execution()
{
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") { x.style.display = "block";} 
  else {x.style.display = "none";}
  
  var qno1=random(); 
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ques[qno1];
  
  var qno2=random(); 
  if(qno1==qno2)
    qno2=random();
   document.getElementById("demos").innerHTML = ques[qno2];
}
```

---

in the above code I am trying to generate random questions. this is only javascript part of my code.
starting with first the 2 arrays are questions and sol respectively. code is executing successfully but I have problem in validation part. for validation i want to pass qno1 value to validation function on pressing of submit button in HTML button tag. please help me with this code to execute and how can we share common variable among 2 functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to scope the vars to outside of your functions so you can use them in both.

```
        var ques=["Qno 1", "Qno 2","Qno 3","Qno 4","Qno 5","Qno 6","Qno 7","Qno 8","Qno 9","Qno 10"];
var ans  =[1,2,3,4,5,6, 7,8,9,10];

//move scope of vars
var qno1

function random()
{
  var qno=Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) );
  return qno;
}

function validate (qno)// use it here by passing it in
{
  var Rans=document.getElementById("numb").value;
  if (Rans == ans[qno])
     alert("validated!!!");
  else 
     alert("Not a valid entry.. declined!!!");
}
function execution()
{
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") { x.style.display = "block";} 
  else {x.style.display = "none";}
  
// set here
  qno1=random(); 
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ques[qno1];
  
  var qno2=random(); 
  if(qno1==qno2)
    qno2=random();
   document.getElementById("demos").innerHTML = ques[qno2];
}

// call it wherever
validate(qno1)
```